# Implementing parallel static content download in the browser?

Tags: http, browser, caching, performance

We are looking at adjusting our web pages so we [split](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#split) our calls for static data across sub-domains. In order to do this we must:

- Always serve the same content from the same sub-domain so it remains cached
- Try and serve roughly the same amount of content from each of the sub-domains
- Try to do this in an automatic way on a per-page basis, i.e. avoid hand-coding every image and having to maintain that
- Come up with a solution that will work in our dev/test/production environments
- Do not impact on page processing times on the server

We are creating our HTML pages using a J2EE application server and I am trying to find the best approach in order to implement this for all our web pages.

As far as I can see it, if we do this while rendering the HTML page, we will need to have a list of images with sizes stored somewhere that we can reference while we build the page. If an image is to be written out on the HTML page we will need to determine how many other images are being served from that sub-domain for this user at that point in page processing. Then we assign this image to a sub-domain and somehow remember that for the user session (or longer).

Or am I over-complicating this? Would it be easier to maintain a list of images on each page on the site, and (offline) determine which sub-domain each image lives on, and just use that consistently for all users?

I was thinking there might be a way to do this in the browser using JavaScript but I think the overhead for each page render might be a little high.

I know the topic is a bit fuzzy but if anyone has implemented this I'd love to hear of your experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your situation is remarkably unusual, I think you're most likely over-complicating it.

First, your approach with parallel downloads here disregards one of the other key elements of client-side performance, which is to *minimize* the number of different domains you use. You must strike a balance between the two. [From the same guidelines you linked to](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#dns_lookups):

> split [images, scripts, CSS, Flash, etc.] across **at least two but no more than four** hostnames *(em added)*

So the simplest solution is also likely the most optimal for most situations:

- A domain for images;

  - In situations with a large volume of design-element images (e.g. rounded corners, bullets, etc) and a separate volume of content images, consider serving them from two - e.g. `static-images.mydomain.com` and `content-images.mydomain.com`
- One for scripts, CSS and Flash;

  - If one of those in particular takes up considerably more than the others, consider splitting it out into a separate domain from the others.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The vast majority of our HTTP requests are for images so we are happy to leave JavaScript and CSS out of it. The approach you suggest is simple and probably lends itself well across most pages.